# change In document style.. without replacing it

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I found this on the web

```
function largeFont() {
  const dStyle = document.querySelector('style');
  dStyle.innerHTML = 'p {font-size: 2rem;}';
}
```

But this takes everything inside of `<style></style>` wipes it clean and puts in "p {font-size: 2rem;}". Is it possible to change  specific thing inside of `<style></style>` like

```
document.querySelector('style').body
or 
document.querySelector('style').#box
document.querySelector('style').box.background-color
```

Or whatever.
I know how to do inline, But I would rather not in this case.
I mean, I guess I could just parse the whole thing and find replace that text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the style is inline on the page, you can insert content into it with `+=`, which will keep the existing content.

```
const dStyle = document.querySelector('style');
dStyle.innerHTML += 'p {font-size: 2rem;}';
//              ^^^
```

If the style is not inline on the page, or you don't want to use the above approach, you can also [use `insertRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule).

```
const sheet = document.querySelector('style').sheet;
sheet.insertRule(`
p {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
`,
sheet.cssRules.length
);
```